# Entity browser widget in custom config form

Tags: 8, entities

I am able to render the entity browser button in custom configuration form.
But, after selecting the image it does not get displayed in the
 form, has anyone integrated in custom form so far ?

```
$form['content_link'] = [
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#parents' => ['content_link_wrapper'],
    '#weight' => -3,
    'widget' => [
      '#title' => t('Content Link'),
      '#description' => t('The content to be linked in the menu.'),
      '#field_name' => 'content_link',
      '#field_parents' => [],
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#parents' => ['content_link'],
      '#tree' => TRUE,
      '#id' => 'edit-content-link',
      '#type' => 'details',
      '#open' => TRUE,
      'target_id' => [
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#id' => 'edit-content-link-target-id',
        '#attributes' => [
          'id' => 'edit-content-link-target-id',
        ],
        '#default_value' => "",
        '#ajax' => [
          'callback' => [
            '\Drupal\entity_browser\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\EntityReferenceBrowserWidget',
            'updateWidgetCallback',
          ],
          'wrapper' => 'edit-content-link',
          'event' => 'entity_browser_value_updated',
        ],
      ],
      'entity_browser' => [
        '#type' => 'entity_browser',
        '#entity_browser' => 'image_browser_dropzonejs',
        '#cardinality' => 1,
        '#selection_mode' => 'selection_append',
        '#default_value' => [],
        '#custom_hidden_id' => 'edit-content-link-target-id',
        '#process' => [
          [
            '\Drupal\entity_browser\Element\EntityBrowserElement','processEntityBrowser'
          ],
        ],
      ],
      'current' => [
        '#theme_wrappers' => ['container'],
        '#attributes' => [
          'class' => 'entities-list',
        ],
        'items' => [],
      ],
      '#attached' => [
        'library' => [
          'entity_browser/entity_reference',
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ];
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: See the duplicate topic, especially the module recommendation in the [comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/256453/8-4-use-entity-browser-in-a-module-block-from-in-same-way-as-i-would-in-a-cust/256460#comment316572_256460)  from @sonfd.